# `New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -RunOnlyIfIdle` not working

Tags: scheduled-tasks, powershell-4.0

```
$Sta = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Cmd"
$Stset = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -RunOnlyIfIdle -IdleDuration 00:02:00 -IdleWaitTimeout 02:30:00
Register-ScheduledTask Task01 -Action $Sta -Settings $Stset
(Get-ScheduledTask Task01).Settings.RunOnlyIfIdle
```

via https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649824(v=wps.630).aspx

The `RunOnlyIfIdle` property isn’t actually set when registering (or updating an existing task with `Set-ScheduledTask`). You can also confirm that the option doesn’t have the option set in the Task Scheduler UI.

Answer (score 3):

Before anyone else wastes a day on this, the `RunOnlyIfIdle` argument is in fact ignored by the TaskScheudler Cmdlets in Windows 10. You’re not doing anything wrong, it’s just broken straight outta the chocolate factory.

Update: I wrote up an article on the [problems with the Task Scheduler cmdlets](https://www.slightfuture.com/devel/idle-task-scheduler-powershell) and documented a work-around.